# No Title Bar Issue and Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I am developing an application with a custom title bar. The form design requires it to be resizable. Keeping in mind that it has a custom title bar, using the normal route to remove the title bar in the custom form is not working. It appears that the Windows 10 API is forcing a small white "chunk" to remain at the top of the screen above the title bar.

My question to you is this: Has anyone encountered this issue, and do you know a fix or a work-around so that we can get the forms to look correct in Windows 10?

Here is my current code:

```
Dim testform As New Form
testform.Width = 350
testform.Height = 100
testform.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
testform.ControlBox = False
testform.Text = String.Empty

testform.Show()
```

We tested for the API issue due to a suggestion by another support forum that has since seemed to be exhausted as far as help. I compiled our existing code and ran the executable on a Windows 7 machine. On the Windows 7 machine the form opens properly with 0 space between the top of the ClientRectangle and the Form.

Comment: Create the Form with the border set to None, then override WndProc() and handle the [WM_NCHITTEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message.  Set `m.Result` to the appropriate edge constant based on where the cursor is currently located in relation to the edges of the form.  This will allow the borderless form to be resized like a sizable form...

Comment: @Idle_Mind - Thank you for the advice! I am not currently in front of the machine, nor am I familiar with the code your have suggested. I will look into these functions and see how I can apply them and will get back to you as soon as I know more.

Comment: I am trying to figure out these `WndProc` Overrides. Each example I found seems to effect code at a global level. How do I make sure this only effects _one particular form_ in a multi-form project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do (something) like what you want.  My VB is *really* rusty, so make sure you test and debug this carefully.

First Add a Form to your project.  For this example I've left the name `Form1` but you probably want to change that to something meaningful. On that form I set the `BorderStyle` property to `None`. (That's the only change I made)

The code for `Form1` is as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Const WM_NCHITTEST As Integer = &H84
    Public Const BorderSize As Integer = 10

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST Then
            Dim x As Integer = m.LParam.ToInt32 And &HFFFF
            Dim y As Integer = (m.LParam.ToInt32 >> 16) And &HFFFF
            Dim p As Point = New Point(x, y)
            If Me.Bounds.Contains(p) Then
                Dim top As Boolean = Math.Abs(Me.Bounds.Y - y) < BorderSize
                Dim bottom As Boolean = Math.Abs(Me.Bounds.Bottom - y) < BorderSize
                Dim left As Boolean = Math.Abs(Me.Bounds.X - x) < BorderSize
                Dim right As Boolean = Math.Abs(Me.Bounds.Right - x) < BorderSize
                If top And left Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTTOPLEFT
                ElseIf top And right Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTTOPRIGHT
                ElseIf bottom And left Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTBOTTOMLEFT
                ElseIf bottom And right Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTBOTTOMRIGHT
                ElseIf top Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTTOP
                ElseIf bottom Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTBOTTOM
                ElseIf left Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTLEFT
                ElseIf right Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTRIGHT
                Else
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTCAPTION
                End If
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Additionally, somewhere in that makes sense in your project include the following enum.  (I've stripped out the values I'm not using, but they are all available in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))  For the purposes of this demonstration I placed it directly beneath the `End Class` for `Form1`.

```
Public Enum NCHITTEST
    HTBOTTOM = 15
    HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16
    HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17
    HTCAPTION = 2
    HTLEFT = 10
    HTRIGHT = 11
    HTTOP = 12
    HTTOPLEFT = 13
    HTTOPRIGHT = 14
End Enum
```

The way it's implemented, there is an invisible 10px border where the mouse will change to the resize cursor. This is controlled by the `BorderSize` constant. You can move the form by clicking and dragging anywhere in the background. (That's what `HTCAPTION` does.)

Comment: It's not a property, its just a constant. You could certainly make it into a property if you want, or get rid of it entirely, and just put the value into the 4 calculations.  ie- `Math.Abs(Me.Bounds.Y - y) < BorderSize` could be `Math.Abs(Me.Bounds.Y - y) < 10`

Comment: I created a new project and tested this out -- it worked great! I am going to see what I can do to incorporate it into my existing project to see if it works with the dynamically-created form somehow.

Comment: The code worked great on the test project. However, when implementing this into my code for the actual project it does not seem to understand what NCHITTEST is. I have inserted it pretty much the same way, except it is embedded in code that _generates_ a form, and is not a form in itself. Do I have to set a namespace for NCHITTEST somewhere?

Comment: You will have to add a form at some point, you can't override `WndProc` otherwise.  Add a `Form` to your project, give it a friendly name like `BorderlessForm`, put the code inside it, then use that in the code that _generates_ the form. (ie- `Dim testForm as New BorderlessForm`)  The `NCHITTEST` enumeration has to be somewhere visible to the code that's using it, whether it's in the same file, or in another file. Also Enum is a Type, so it can't go inside a method, and should probably be outside a class.

Comment: Figured it out, @theB. I just had the Enum information in two different places. Cleared that up and it worked like a charm! :) Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

TheB had the best answer, and I had to amend it slightly to work with my coding. Thank you for all of the help, sir!

So, when altering this code to work with a dynamically-created control a few changes needed to be made. Here is how I got it to work:

**Create a new class specifically named: SubclassHWND.vb**
(As gathered from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311317))

```vb
Public Class SubclassHWND
    Inherits NativeWindow

    Public Const WM_NCHITTEST = &H84
    Public Const BorderSize As Integer = 10
    Public frm As Form = Nothing

    Public Sub setFrm(ByVal sender As Form)
        frm = sender
    End Sub

    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        if m.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST Then
            Dim x As Integer = m.LParam.ToInt32 And &HFFFF
            Dim y As Integer = (m.LParam.ToInt32 >> 16) And &HFFFF
            Dim p As Point = New Point(x, y)
            If frm.Bounds.Contains(p) Then
                Dim top As Boolean = Math.Abs(frm.Bounds.Y - y) < BorderSize
                Dim bottom As Boolean = Math.Abs(frm.Bounds.Bottom - y) < BorderSize
                Dim left As Boolean = Math.Abs(frm.Bounds.X - x) < BorderSize
                Dim right As Boolean = Math.Abs(frm.Bounds.Right - x) < BorderSize
                If top And left Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTTOPLEFT
                ElseIf top And right Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTTOPRIGHT
                ElseIf bottom And left Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTBOTTOMLEFT
                ElseIf bottom And right Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTBOTTOMRIGHT
                ElseIf top Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTTOP
                ElseIf bottom Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTBOTTOM
                ElseIf left Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTLEFT
                ElseIf right Then
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTRIGHT
                Else
                    m.Result = NCHITTEST.HTCAPTION
                End If
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        Debug.WriteLine(m.ToString())
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Enum NCHITTEST
    HTBOTTOM = 15
    HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16
    HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17
    HTCAPTION = 2
    HTLEFT = 10
    HTRIGHT = 11
    HTTOP = 12
    HTTOPLEFT = 13
    HTTOPRIGHT = 14
End Enum
```

This is basically the same exact code that @TheB supplied me with for the fix earlier with a couple of changes. We went ahead and created a new `Public frm` variable. We set this in the next set of code so we can reference the dynamic form that the `WndProc` evaluation will Override.

In the form generation code we added these lines to create the re-sizable window that has no title bar API in Windows 10:

```vb
newForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
newForm.ControlBox = False
newForm.Text = String.Empty
Dim s As SubclassHWND = New SubclassHWND()
s.setFrm(newForm)
s.AssignHandle(newForm.Handle)
```

Now every dynamically-created form in the project uses the Overrides that we specified in `SubclassHWND.vb`! Thanks go out to everyone and all of their valuable input.